# GitHub actions workflow: how to access fromJSON dictionary value using the key stored in a variable?

Tags: json, github, github-actions, workflow

Consider the GitHub action workflow file below.
I would like to access json dictionary value using key stored in a variable.
The first run command shows how it is done when the key (`foo2` in this example) is specified explicitly, so not taken from variable.
The subsequent run commands are my desperate attempts to get the dict value using the key in the `var_foo` variable but they don't work.

```
name: test fromJSON
on:  workflow_dispatch
env:
  myjson: '{"foo1" : "bar1", "foo2": "bar2"}'
  var_foo: 'foo2'
jobs:
  job1:
    runs-on: self-hosted
    steps:
      - run: echo ${{ fromjson(env.myjson).foo2 }} # Outputs 'bar2' as expected 
                                                   # but foo2 property is explicitly
                                                   # specified, not taken from var_foo 
      - run: echo ${{ fromjson(env.myjson).env.var_foo }} # Doesn't work, outputs empty string
      - run: echo ${{ fromjson(env.myjson).${{ env.var_foo }} }} # Breaks worflow file
      - run: echo ${{ fromjson(env.myjson).format('{0}', env.var_foo) }} # Breaks worflow file
      - run: echo ${{ format(fromjson({0}).{1}, env.myjson, env.var_foo) }} # Breaks worflow file
      - run: echo ${{ format(fromjson('{0}').'{1}', env.myjson, env.var_foo) }} # Breaks worflow file
```

I know I could use shell command such as 
`- run: echo ${{ env.myjson }} |yq -r ".${{ env.var_foo }}"` 
but this requires complex environment setup to install yq tool on the GitHub runner side so I would prefer to avoid that.

Comment: Untested: `${{ fromJSON(env.myjson)[env.var_foo] }}`?

Comment: You are right! That works, thank you. Ironically I tried square brackets too but at that time I had a typo in the expression that's why it didn't work to me and I discarded this attempt.
Feel free to respond to my question if you wish and I'll accept it.
Thank you again.
Specifically what I needed was ${{ fromJSON(env.myjson).dict_name[env.var_foo] }} or ${{ fromJSON(env.myjson)['dict_name'][env.var_foo] }}

Comment: Alternative: you can use `jq` + `bash`, as both are preinstalled on all images; it looks a little better than `fromJSON` syntax: `jq -r '.foo2' <<< "$myjson"`. 

Live example: https://github.com/rotators/gha/blob/91bb4a571f6bf1193b6de89d99d955bbfe360ffc/get-last-commit/action.yml#L78 and below